# Run an app by calling a contact in phone book?

Tags: android, ionic2

I am looking for a solution to run an app by calling a contact in my android Phone Book. I can not find a description or explanation about a functionality like this.

Does someone can give me a hint how i can achieve it?

Phone Os:android
Dev: ionic2

Comment: Please explain, in much greater detail, what "run an app by calling a contact" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare I assume this means like dial `#123`, and an app will open as a result

Comment: Exactly @cricket_007 : i save a contact with the Number #123. An if i call this contact via Short call an app should tun.

Comment: That would require modification of the dialer of the phone, I assume. I'm not aware of such a feature. I know that certain carriers have special numbers, and theres codes for reaching hidden screens. (see http://www.askvg.com/google-android-hidden-secret-codes/), but even detecting outgoing phone calls with some broadcast receiver / service seems like a strange idea.

Answer (score -1):

```
<button ion-button (click)="dailNumber();">click me</button>
```

inside your .ts file

```
dailNumber(){
  window.location = 'tel:8489949143';
}
```

inside your config.xml file add this line

config.xml

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
```

check this website it will do the trick http://pointdeveloper.com/ionic-2-beginner-dial-a-number-in-ionic-2-apps/